# Why did the Infinity stone just lay around when it is so powerful?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy, infinity-stones

In the beginning of the Guardians of the Galaxy movie, Star-Lord walks around and has no trouble finding the Infinity Stone. Seconds later, the other Troopers arrive as well.

Why did no one before find it? Or search for it?

According to [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19717/infinity-gems-if-they-are-so-powerful-why-cant-anyone-find-them) the Stones are searched for. But was one of them laying around like that particular stone?

Is there a plot about this in one of the comics?

Comment: “Star-Lord walks around and has no trouble finding the Infinity Stone.” It’s easy to find something when you know where it is.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Marvel Cinematic Universe wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Morag) the planet is called Morag. The sea lowers every 300 years to reveal the temple the [Orb](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Orb) was in.

Comment: So nobody has scobba diver siutes in this universe?

Comment: @Fulli: correct. People went to every planet in the galaxy, and searched everywhere, except in the oceans due to the lack of scuba equipment. *Or* I guess it’s possible that no-one searched on this particular planet because no-one knew the stone was there, but scuba seems more likely.

Comment: One possible explanation is that no one knew it was there, but when the water receded, the Orb was able to be detected. Its energy signature was being blocked by all the water. (This sounds a little Star Trek-ish)

Comment: @Dennis_E: You'd be surprised at how effective water is in [blocking things](https://what-if.xkcd.com/29/). As for EM, anything but *extremely* low frequencies (in the sub-kHz range) are blocked completely by only a few meters of water.